# optimising multi pass join in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, union

I have a single table and want to get distinct values from each column.

```sql
select distinct 'customer', customer from sales
union
select distinct 'product',product from sales
```

In the example, MySQL does two full passes of the (huge) table.

I'm trying to get distinct values from many columns, so in fact the query would do 6 full passes of the table. Indexing isn't an option in this case.

How can I persuade MySQL to do this in a single pass ?

Comment: change union to union all, add indexes to all needed columns, this will reduce to 6, right now it is more passes

Answer (score 0):

You can try unpivot approach

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 'customer' 
            WHEN type = 2 THEN 'product' 
       END type,
       CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN customer
            WHEN type = 2 THEN product
       END value
  FROM sales s CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT 1 type UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
) t
 ORDER BY type
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcbbd/2)** demo